# Passing data between Intents causes app to 'unexpectedly close'

Tags: android, android-intent, extras

I am trying to transfer an int value between two activities using intents, but my app keeps crashing. When I comment out the transfer of any data and simply use an intent, everything seems to work. I cannot tell what is wrong.

Activity 1 (HeartRateActivity):

```
//Imports

public class HeartRateActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button nextActivity;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    nextActivity = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextActivity);

    nextActivity.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(HeartRateActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("age", 2);
    startActivity(intent);
}

    });

}
}
```

My NextActivity.java

```
package com.heartRate;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class NextActivity extends Activity {
TextView display;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.next);
       int age = getIntent().getIntExtra("age", 0);
       display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
       display.setText(age);
}
}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.heartRate" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".HeartRateActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" 
                             />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NextActivity" 
      android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

My main.xml (used by HeartRateActivity)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
 <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
 />
 <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 android:id="@+id/nextActivity" android:text="nextActivity"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

My next.xml(used by NextActivity) is similar and i dont think thats the issue...:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <TextView android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/display"></TextView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

I would appreciate help in solving this issue! Thank you

Comment: Take a look at LogCat and copy/paste the exception that you're getting here.

Comment: Could you put the full stack trace please?

Comment: It also gives an error at line in NextActivity -- display.setText(age);

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
display.setText(age);
```

with

```
display.setText(Integer.toString(age));
```

If you provide an `int` as a parameter, it uses it as a resource ID, which, in this case, obviously doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

just try do like this.

display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);

display.setText(Integer.toString(age));

and surely it will work

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your Id and Intent Destination all must be Ok.

then just put between intent from initialize ans start.
with put

```
intent.putExtra("age", Double);
```

from get this.

```
double d = getIntent().getStringExtra("age");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `R.id.display` is a valid `TextView` in your `next` layout.

Comment: 06-18 03:46:21.749: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.heartRate/.HeartRateActivity }
06-18 03:46:21.779: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(881): Shutting down VM
06-18 03:46:21.788: DEBUG/dalvikvm(881): DestroyJavaVM waiting for non-daemon threads to exit
06-18 03:46:21.788: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(881): ERROR: thread attach failed
06-18 03:46:21.818: DEBUG/dalvikvm(881): DestroyJavaVM shutting VM down

Comment: 06-18 03:46:21.818: DEBUG/dalvikvm(881): HeapWorker thread shutting down
06-18 03:46:21.829: DEBUG/dalvikvm(881): HeapWorker thread has shut down
06-18 03:46:21.838: DEBUG/jdwp(881): JDWP shutting down net...
06-18 03:46:21.838: INFO/dalvikvm(881): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-18 03:46:21.848: DEBUG/dalvikvm(881): VM cleaning up
06-18 03:46:21.899: DEBUG/dalvikvm(881): LinearAlloc 0x0 used 639500 of 5242880 (12%)

Comment: 06-18 03:46:26.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(865): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-18 03:46:27.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(865): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.heartRate/com.heartRate.NextActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2
06-18 03:46:27.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(865):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
06-18 03:46:27.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(865):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)

Comment: 06-18 03:46:27.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(865):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
06-18 03:46:27.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(865):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
06-18 03:46:27.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(865):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 03:46:27.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(865):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-18 03:46:27.008: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(865):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)

Comment: Glendon's answer looks like it.

Answer (score -1):

Just so we're clear, you're saying when you include the ...

```
intent.putExtra("age", 2);
```

in the sending Activity, and the ...

```
int age = getIntent().getIntExtra("age", 0);
```

in the receiving Activity, the application crashes or expereinces problems?  And, by excluding those 2 statements the application performs normally?  I'm just curious what does LogCat show?  Even though you application is crashing LogCat will have several entries as to what was happening just prior to the close.

Comment: yes, if I dont pass any information, it works fine. The app says it has closed unexpectedly and does not move on to the next screen.